# Making binomial coefficients out of binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients, divisibility

For binomial coefficients, we have
$\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$

Now, fix a positive integer $s$ and define a function $n?=\binom{n}{s} \cdot \binom{n-1}{s} \cdot ... \cdot \binom{s}{s}$ or $1$ if $n<s$

Define "new" "binomial coefficients" as $\binom{n}{k}_{?} =\frac{n?}{k?(n-k)?} $

> **Question 1** : Are all numbers $\binom{n}{k}_?$ integers? (when $0\le k \le n$)

This is not obvious to me: at first glance, it seems that the expression $n?/(k? (n-k)?)$ contains $n$ binomial coefficients in both numerator and denominator so we could multiply by $(s!)^n$ and receive $$\frac{(n(n-1)...(n-s+1)) \cdot ( (n-1) (n-2) ... (n-s) ) \cdot (...) }{(k(k-1)...(k-s+1)) \cdot ((k-1) (k-2) ... (k-s)) \cdot (...)} = \frac{n! (n-1)! ... (n-s+1)!}{k! (k-1)! ... (k-s+1)! \cdot (n-k)! (n-k-1)! ...(n-k-s+1)! }$$ which can be shown to be integer (it's just $\binom{n}{k} \binom{n-1}{k-1} ... \binom{n-s+1}{k-s+1}$ times some integer). But it is not equal to $\binom{n}{k}_?$, for example, when $s = 2, n = 5, k=3$, $\binom{5}{3}_? = \frac{\binom{5}{2} \binom{4}{2}}{\binom{2}{2}} = 60$ but $\frac{5!4!}{3!2! \cdot 2! 1!} = 120$. It is strange, because I don't see the error. If I'm not mistaken, it comes from the fact that $n? = 1$ when $n< s$. Indeed, when we write $\binom{n}{k}_?= \frac{[n][n-1]...[n-k+1]}{[k][k-1]...[s]}$ and $n-k+1 \ge s$ we get that the fraction above should be divided by $(s!)^{k-(k-s+1)}=(s!)^{s-1}$. (which is the missing $(2!)^{2-1}=2$ for $s=2, n=5, k=3$)

But if that fraction gets divided by $(s!)^{something} $, I do not see how to prove that these numbers are integers. (I checked some small numbers, it seems, they are)

Also, if it is indeed true, there's also another question

> **Question 2**: what if we repeat the same procedure one more time, that is fix some $ s_2$ and let $n?? = \binom{n}{s_2}_? \binom{n-1}{s_2}_? ...$ and $\binom{n}{k}_{??} = \frac{n??}{k??(n-k)??}$ Will those numbers also be integers? And what if we do this several times?

Comment: Very interesting question! For $s=2$, Question 1 boils down to $2 \mid k \dbinom{n}{k} \dbinom{n-1}{k} = n \dbinom{n-1}{k-1} \dbinom{n-1}{k} = \left(n-1\right) \dbinom{n}{k} \dbinom{n-2}{k-1}$, which is true (e.g., by Lucas's theorem, or simply because one of $n$ and $n-1$ is even) but not obvious.

Comment: I think there's a more general question here that's interesting too, which is: if $P(x)$ is an integer-valued (but not necessarily $\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$) polynomial, defining $n!_P=\prod_{i=1}^nP(i)$, under what conditions on $P$ is ${n\choose k}_P$ integral for all $n,k$? Your question is of course the special case $P(x)={x\choose i}$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: Unfortunately, due to the extra rule for $n < k$, the product is not a product of polynomial values.

Comment: An answer to your Question 1 just essentially appeared on the arXiv. Indeed, your numbers $\dbinom{n}{k}_?$ are obviously integers if $k < s$ or $n-k < s$, so we WLOG assume that $k \geq s$ and $n-k \geq s$. But then, using the notations of [Johann Cigler, *Pascal’s triangle, Hoggatt matrices, and analogous constructions*, arXiv:2103.01652v1](https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.01652v1), we have $\dbinom{n}{k}_? = \dfrac{\left<n-s+1\right>_s!}{\left<k-s+1\right>_s! \left<n-k-s+1\right>_s!} = \dfrac{\left<k\right>_s!}{\left<k-s+1\right>_s!}\cdot\displaystyle\genfrac<>{0pt}{}{n-s+1}{k}_s$, and ...

Comment: ... the $\displaystyle\genfrac<>{0pt}{}{n-s+1}{k}_s$ term on the right hand side is an integer because of Theorem 2 in Cigler's above-quoted preprint, whereas the $\dfrac{\left<k\right>_s!}{\left<k-s+1\right>_s!}$ term is an integer since $k \geq k-s+1$. Thus, $\dbinom{n}{k}_?$ is an integer. (Please verify.)

Comment: @darijgrinberg Very nice. Thank you.